# R Unlist named list into one string with preserving list names

Tags: r, list

I want to convert one dimensional named list into one single string - row. Names should be preserved and stored as NAME=VALUE pairs separated by semicolon.

**my test list**

```
nl = list(case1="master2", case2=5, case3="master", case4=345)
```

**I tried the following**

```
sapply(names(nl),function(x) paste(x,paste(nl[[x]],collapse="=")))
          case1           case2           case3           case4 
"case1 master2"       "case2 5"  "case3 master"     "case4 345"
```

**what I need is**

```
"case1=master2;case2=5;case3=master;case4=345"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `paste()` to create the "=" separator and collapse with ";". `names()` allows you to access the names in the list.

UPDATED with @Dason's suggestion.

```r
paste(names(nl),nl,sep="=",collapse=";" )

[1] "case1=master2;case2=5;case3=master;case4=345"
```

Comment: Just do paste(names(nl),nl,sep="=",collapse=";" )

Comment: Great! I knew there is a simple way to reach the objective, thx!